# Proof that the inverse of exponentiation is a root

Tags: real-analysis

I'm going through Terrence Tao's  Real Analysis 1.
In which he defines exponentiation by a natural number recursively.

By $x^0=1$ and $x^{n+1}=x^n \times x$.

After establishing real numbers and the sepremum. He defines the $n$-th root of $x$ for $n$ a natural number $x$ a positive real by

$\sqrt[n]{x}=\sup\{y \in \textbf{R}\mid y \geq 0, y^n \leq x\}$

He then states that for $y$ and $x$ positive reals

1. If $y=\sqrt[n]{x}$ then $y^n=x$
2. If $y^n=x$ then $y=\sqrt[n]{x}$

Leaving the proof of these to the reader. If anyone is willing to help me figure how to proceed with this proof that would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try assuming $y^n>x$ or $y^n<x$?

Comment: The second statement is false : example : $(-1)^2 = 1$ but $-1 \neq \sqrt{1}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I think we can assume the nth root is a real number.

Comment: @Wakem What do you mean ? Of course the root is a real number, but this has nothing to do with my comment.

Comment: I would just use induction for the first statement.

Comment: Sorry I  forgot to add that x was positive I've edited the question to fix that problem.

Comment: To do 1) I'd attempt to prove that for all $w \ge 0$ that if $w^n < x$ then there exists a $v: v > w$ so that $v^n \le x$.  Therefore no such non-negative $w$ where $w^n < x$ can be the sup and therefore the $\sup^n \ge x$.